# How do you change multiple tags with specific conditions?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to create a way to replace tags and content within a string based on a specific condition.

I am able to fully replace the string as intended but this would affect everything with the same initial tag. I can also replace the text within the URL if it contained a string.

The issue is when I'm trying to replace the following:

```
<figure class="media"><img src="removethis?=banners/image.jpg"></figure>
<figure class="media"><img src="removethis?=thumbnails/image.jpg"></figure>
```

If I do the following:

```
var test = $("figure.media").html();
if (test.includes("removethis?=")) {
    var img = $("img").attr("src");
    var replaceIMG = img.replace("removethis?=", "images/");
    $("figure.media").replaceWith('<div class="img"><img src="' + replaceIMG + '"></div>');
}
```

Then I am able to remove "removethis?=" without any issues, however, it will affect both items. If I code it like this:

```
var test = $("figure.media").html().includes("banners");
if (test === true) {
    var test2 = $("figure.media").html();
    if (test2.includes("removethis?=")) {
        var img = $("img").attr("src");
        var replaceIMG = img.replace("removethis?=", "images/");
        $("figure.media").replaceWith('<div class="img"><img src="' + replaceIMG + '"></div>');
    }
}
```

Then I am able to check whether the condition has "banners" or "thumbnails", but adding the previous code again results in both items being changed. Is there a way to accomplish just changing one of the items rather than both? This would also need to work if there are multiple of the same condition.

Comment: You can get the first figure element using "document.getElementsByTagName('figure')[0]", then you can alter the element any way you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over each element and within that loop address only the current instance.

You can use the `removethis` in the selector to filter only the relevant ones and then use `attr(attributeName,function)` to do all the looping and then finally use `wrap()` to insert the new div

Something like:

```
$("figure.media img[src*='removethis?=']").attr('src', function(_, curr) {
  return curr.replace("removethis?=", "images/");
}).wrap('<div class="img">');
```

Comment: This worked spot on. The only remaining issue which I forgot to mention is how would one change the IMG tag to an IFRAME tag instead? When adding the ```replaceWith()``` the URLs all suddenly become the same per object.

Comment: That is a completely different question. All the comments and answers would become irrelevant in this one by changing the scope so much and also requires a complete rewrite of the question